# Div Overlapping With Another Div With image

Tags: html, css

I create a menubar and make it transparent and I add an image in my container div to look image behind menubar after this when I create another div it overlapping each other I want second div visible below container div

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.top_nav {
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  position: relative;
}
.container {
  height: 638px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-position: center;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
.container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 638px;
}
.details {
  height: 638px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="top_nav"></div>
</header>
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://www.100resilientcities.org/page/-/100rc/img/blog/rsz_resilientcity_headphoto.jpg">
  <div id="short-des"></div>
</div>
<div class="details"></div>
```

I want div name detail to show below the container div image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kz95Q.jpg)

Comment: You can use pseudo elements `:before` or `:after`

Answer (score 2):

don't use `position:absolute` on `container` , but use it on `header` . so `header` will stay on top of the `container` , and `details` will stay under container

see snippet below or fiddle > [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fyhfzx2w/1/)

let me know if it helps

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

header { 
 position:absolute;
  z-index:100;
  width:100%;
  height:80px
 }
.top_nav{
    height: 80px;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    position: relative;
}

.container{
    height: 638px;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-position: center;
    top: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}

.container img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 638px;
}

.details{
    height: 638px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background:red;

}
```

```html
<header>
    <div class="top_nav">

    </div>
</header>
    <div class="container">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
    <div id="short-des">

</div>
</div>
<div class="details">
</div>
```